# How to robustly debug gevent 'This operation would block forever' exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, gevent, monkeypatching

I have some concurrent code using gevent:

```
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

....

jobs = [gevent.spawn(self.generate_resource_cache, idx, resource, id_fields_map[resource])
                for idx, resource in enumerate(available_resources)]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

My `generate_resource_cache` method is using `requests` library which means I have to mankeypatch `gevent`.

With `requests`, I'm using custom session:

```
def get_session(self):
    s = Settings.Instance()
    if not self.session:
        retry = Retry(total=s.TOTAL_RETRIES, backoff_factor=s.BACKOFF_FACTOR,
                status_forcelist=(range(400, 421) + range(500, 505)))
        size = s.CONCURRENT_SIZE
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=size, pool_maxsize=size, pool_block=True, max_retries=retry)
        self.session = requests_cache.CachedSession(s.CACHE_NAME, backend='sqlite',
            fast_save=s.FAST_SAVE, allowable_methods=('GET', 'POST')) if s.CACHING else requests.Session()
        if s.PROXIES:
            self.session.proxies = s.PROXIES
        self.session.headers.update({'X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE' : 'get'})
        self.session.mount('http://', adapter)
        self.session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return self.session
```

After few hours of running this script it prints to stdout:

```
WARNING:root:epoll module not found; using select()
```

And to stderr:

```
Exception caught: This operation would block forever
```

I'm wondering what can I do to better understand why I'm getting this exception in the first place and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Does it print anything *else* to stderr?  Say, a traceback?